# how to fill missing values based on column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have this dataframe in pandas:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
        "n": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "x"],
        "t": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        "v": [10,20,30,40,50,60]
    })
```

how can it be filled with missing values such that every value of column `t` has the same entries in column `n`? that is every `t` value should have entries for `a, b, c, x`, recorded as `NaN` if they are missing:

```
   n  t   v
   a  0  10
   b  0  20
   c  0  30
   x  NaN NaN
   a  1  40
   b  1  50
   c  NaN NaN
   x  1  60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want every value in `"n"` to be equally distributed among sub-groups grouped by `"t"`. I'm also hoping that those `"n"` cannot be duplicated in these sub-groups.

Considering these assumptions to be true, [`pd.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) seems to be a good option for this use case. Here, the values under `"n"` would constitute the column names, `"t"` would be the grouped index, and the contents of the `DF` get filled by the values under `"v"`. Later stack the `DF` while preserving `NaN` entries and fill it's corresponding cells in `"t"` with `.loc` accessor.

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, "v", "t", "n", "first").stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name="v")
df1.loc[df1['v'].isnull(), "t"] = np.nan
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***plan***

- get unique values of column `'n'`. we'll use this to `reindex` by
- we'll apply `f` to our groups within each group of column `'t'` reindexing by `idx` will ensure we get all elements of `idx` represented for each group of unique `'t'`
- we set the index so that we can `reindex` in a bit

---

```
idx = df.n.unique()
f = lambda x: x.reindex(idx)
df.set_index('n').groupby('t', group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index()

   n    t     v
0  a  0.0  10.0
1  b  0.0  20.0
2  c  0.0  30.0
3  x  NaN   NaN
4  a  1.0  40.0
5  b  1.0  50.0
6  c  NaN   NaN
7  x  1.0  60.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use, if in `df` are no `NaN` before - create `MultiIndex` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), `NaN` in `t` are set by column `v`:

```
cols = ["n", "t"]
df1 = df.set_index(cols)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=cols)
df1 = df1.reindex(mux).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index()
df1['t'] = df1['t'].mask(df1['v'].isnull())
print (df1)
   n    t     v
0  a  0.0  10.0
1  b  0.0  20.0
2  c  0.0  30.0
3  x  NaN   NaN
4  a  1.0  40.0
5  b  1.0  50.0
6  c  NaN   NaN
7  x  1.0  60.0
```

Another solution for adding NaN is [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method:

```
cols = ["n", "t"]
df1 = df.set_index(cols)['v'].unstack().stack(dropna=False)
df1 = df1.sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(name='v')
df1['t'] = df1['t'].mask(df1['v'].isnull())
print (df1)
    n    t     v
0  a  0.0  10.0
1  b  0.0  20.0
2  c  0.0  30.0
3  x  NaN   NaN
4  a  1.0  40.0
5  b  1.0  50.0
6  c  NaN   NaN
7  x  1.0  60.0
```

But if some `NaN` values need `groupby` with `loc` by [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of `n` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"n": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "x"], 
                       "t": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                       "v": [10,20,30,40,50,np.nan]})
print (df)
   n  t     v
0  a  0  10.0
1  b  0  20.0
2  c  0  30.0
3  a  1  40.0
4  b  1  50.0
5  x  1   NaN

df1 = df.set_index('n')
        .groupby('t', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[df.n.unique()])
        .reset_index()

print (df1)
   n    t     v
0  a  0.0  10.0
1  b  0.0  20.0
2  c  0.0  30.0
3  x  NaN   NaN
4  a  1.0  40.0
5  b  1.0  50.0
6  c  NaN   NaN
7  x  1.0   NaN
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('t', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('n').loc[df.n.unique()])
        .reset_index()
print (df1)
   n    t     v
0  a  0.0  10.0
1  b  0.0  20.0
2  c  0.0  30.0
3  x  NaN   NaN
4  a  1.0  40.0
5  b  1.0  50.0
6  c  NaN   NaN
7  x  1.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're building it wrong. Normally NaN are read in automatically or you specify them. You can manually put in NaN's by `np.nan` if you have `import numpy as np` at the top. Alternatively pandas stores numpy internally and you can get a Nan by `pandas.np.nan`